# Graphical, free debugger for makefie built C++ programs (Windows XP)

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, makefile

The software I develop uses command line makefiles. My environment uses free tools as much as possible. If you were to ask me which version of make I am using I would struggle to specify that, because I have installed mingw, cygwin and dev-cpp. However, I do know its "the free one", not Microsofts, and the one on my path at the moment is from the dev-cpp directory. Anyway thats not the crux of this question.

My code gets pulled from SCM, built, and finally the exe is placed in a bin directory. **I want a *free* full screen *graphical* debugger that can debug this exe.** I'm not looking for an IDE, but maybe the answer will require installing an IDE. I definitely will **not** consider moving away from command line makefiles to IDE equivalents.

I have tried this with MSVC and I *can* do it by attaching to the process after it has started. This is not ideal for two reasons: The tool has to be free and I should be able to debug it from startup. And by the way I will not consider MSVS Express. I already tried it and it kept hanging so it's uninstalled for good now!

In your answer you might want to include instructions as normally these things only work smoothly when you have built the program inside the IDE and I will not be doing that.
The preferred answer will specify a tool that has a small install footprint and works on Linux too. Specify any pre-requisites such as what compiler the code should have been built with. Of course if the instructions are too long then a list of what *you* have installed yourself is a help.

I will certainly *upvote* an answer that explains how I can do this with Dev-CPP, as I already have it installed. That doesn't mean it will be the preferred answer. These are the ideal boxes to be ticked in order of priority.

1. Free (Essential)
2. Decoupled from the build process (Essential)
3. Full Screen Graphical (Essential)
4. Minimalist. Just a debugger would be best. Minimize bloat and learning curve (Ideally)
5. Powerful debugger i.e. you can be reasonably productive with it (Ideally)
6. Cross Platform (Ideally)

4 and 5 may be contradictory, but don't worry. That is where trade offs will be made.

**EDIT:** Some very good answers. Please indicate which of the above boxes you have ticked.

Comment: Why don't you try Cygwin+GDB?

Comment: What? It's THE command line debugger. Its screen size is the size of your command window...

Comment: I have used it like that years ago. Its *not* the solution I'm looking for. Maybe "Full Screen" isn't the expression I should be using.

Comment: Try out [Eclipse CDT](http://eclipse.org/cdt/) or check [Debuggers on Wikipeadia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Debuggers).

Comment: @dma_k I actually have Eclipse installed but I haven't figued out how to open an exe and debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most pro Windows developers use WinDBG which is a UI wrapper around several command line debuggers.  It's a more powerful debugger than MSVC because it can operate in both user and kernel mode and has a flexible command line based set of extensions which can perform a large number of automated tasks.  It's free, as in beer, although probably not as in speech.  Using it is much like using gdb although the UI version does have nice dockable window support for watch variables, locals, threads, memory etc.

It's available as part of the debugging tools for windows (which is free) or the Windows SDK...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009

Comment: All except the last.  It's not cross platform, but it is the best debugger on win32 by far.

Answer (score 2):

Cygwin + http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/

DDD is graphical front-end to gdb.

You have mentioned you are familiar with gdb itself, so this should come naturally.

Comment: What boxes does it tick and do you know of a pre-built Windows binary anywhere? It has to be built from source.

Answer (score 1):

With your toolsets installed, you should be able to use `gdb` already (e.g. included with MinGW). It's minimalistic, but also without any real ui (just command line). To run just call it with your executable as it's parameter: `gdb myexe`. To pass params: `gdb --args myexe first second third`

If you prefer an IDE, you could use almost any IDE and add a makefile project instead of a standard project. Most support this.

For (the IMO) best/most productive debugging under Windows you'll still have to switch to MSVC. There's no way around. Other, free IDEs offer similar stuff and features, but so far none managed to get at least almost on par. It shouldn't get stuck or anything on a semi reasonable modern PC. There might have been some other issue.

Comment: It could have been that it's a 7 year old PC.

Comment: Okay, that's not that good. In that case you might be better off using one of the open source solutions or just a command line debugger (e.g. gdb or windbg).

Comment: It's not so bad. It will easily support a graphical debugger. I'm trying to home in on an Open Source version. Does WinDbg only work for code compiled with MSVC?

Comment: GCC supports different formats for debug information, but I think WinDbg won't be able to handle them. Low level debugging will still be available, but you can't expect full functionality when not using MSVC. Although, keep in mind, that you're able to use MSVC from the command line, in case it's just the UI/IDE causing you trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain why MSVC doesn't work for you for getting the debugger attached before the process actually starts.  Did you try these steps:

1. Copy all your debugging symbols to be in the same directory as the EXE if not already there.
2. Start Visual Studio (Visual C++)
3. From the top menu, select File->Open->Project/Solution. (As if you were about to open a .vcproj file).
4. From the file selection dialog, navigate to the directory of the EXE you want to debug.
5. IF necessary, change the file types drop down to be "all files" or "exe files".  Or just type ***.*** into the file name box to get the dialog to show all files in that folder.
6. Select the EXE.
7. From the top menu select Debug->"Step Over".

If all goes well, the IDE debugger will be pointing to the first line of "main" and you can continue to step through your code.  It may prompt you for the location of the source files.  Just tell it where to find it, and it should find everything else.

Now from the tone of your post,  I can kind of tell you would appreciate something more "low level".  I'll suggest "windbg".  It should work for you as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "symbols" in step 1?

Comment: "Symbols" are information/associations telling the debugger which part of the program is refering to which line of source code. When compiling a program with MSVC, there's a pdb file (program debug database) created that's usually placed next to the resulting binary. That's what he's refering to.

Comment: Upvoting this because the VC debugging from startup does work when these steps are followed.